# Port closed inside docker container

Tags: docker, networking

I'm trying to simulate gps data inside a docker container using `gpsfake`, but fail since all ports seem to be closed.

The docker container is based on the `ubuntu:16.04` image and inside it I've run `apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients`.

Then I try to simulate gps data from a file with

`gpsfake -P 3001 file.nmea`

but get the error

`gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv6 port 3001, Cannot assign requested address`

Trying other ports doesn't seem to work. Upon running `nmap -sTU -O localhost` I get back that `All 2000 scanned ports on localhost (127.0.0.1) are closed`. I tried explicitly opening a port with `ufw allow <port>` but without luck, `nmap -P <port>` returns STATE=closed.

Should I expect ports to be closed? I must be missing something.

Comment: when starting the container you should declale the port available, eg ` docker run -p 3001:3001 my_image`

Comment: I thought that the `-p` flag was about mapping outside-ports to inside-ports. In any case, I tried this but without luck, same problem (`nmap -P 3001 localhost` returns STATE=closed for port 3001/tcp)

Comment: the apt-get command installs the package. But did you start the program as well? what does `ps aux` say?

Comment: Yes I ran `gpsfake` according to the question, but hit Ctrl-C after seeing those error messages, without realising the program actually kept running. After the error message from `gpsd` I get `gpsfake: log cycle of file.nmea begins`. From `ps aux` I get that `root` is running `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gpsfake -P 3001 file.nmea` with PID 1756, and user `gpsd` is running `/usr/sbin/gpsd -b -N -S 3001 -F /tmp/gpsfake-1756.sock -P /tmp/gpsfake-1756.pid` w. PID 1758. Hm, how can I tell which ports the two processes are running? And `gpsd` is a user somehow, w/o su rights perhaps, a problem maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the same. Apparently, the issue is due to the fact that gpsd responds by default only on the localhost. In fact, if you try to connect from within the container (e.g. with gpspipe) you see that gpsd in container is working correctly.
Indeed, gpsd has a flag (-G) to modify this behaviour, but to my knowledge there isn't any option of gpsfake to instruct the latter to launch gpsd with such flag.